# Ночной режим для Google карт API v2?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

*Добрый день-вечер*. Ребят, возможно ли реализовать ночный режим или темное покрытие в `Google Maps API v2`? Или все попытки тщетны?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try {
    // Customise the styling of the base map using a JSON object defined
    // in a raw resource file.
    boolean success = mMap.setMapStyle(MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(this, R.raw.style_json));

    if (!success) {
        Log.e("MapsActivityRaw", "Style parsing failed.");
    }
} catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
    Log.e("MapsActivityRaw", "Can't find style.", e);
}
```

---

[Источник](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/styling)